# Raspberry pi read json typeerror 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I'm having an issue with getting some data from  a webserver, I want to get the temperature in json Format and parse it then into an integer. I try this with my Raspberry Pi 3 in python.

the Code is so far:

```
import json, requests

url='http://stationdata.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/stationlookup?station=IWIEN30&units=metric&v=2.0&format=json'

r=requests.get(url)
result =r.json
temperature = result['stations']['IWIEN30']['temperature']
temperature = int(temperature)
```

When I try to execute this I get: TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no Attribute '**getItem**'

I'm not so experienced with python and the rasperry pi so I guess I'm having just a stupid mistake
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`.json` is a method of the request object; you need to call it.

```
result = r.json()
```